# Extract Github repo to server folder

Tags: php, magento, github, synchronization, extract

I am using PHP to save the master repo zip from Github to a temp folder, extract it then move the folders & files to the main location, but the folders & files are not being moved over the the root folder yet if I set the move destination to a new folder it works..

The issue maybe with folder & file permissions as this root folder is a Magento platform and has chmod magento settings..

Sync.php file

```
//save to folder
$sync_address = 'tmp';

//move to folder
$sync_move = getcwd().'';

//save master to server
$f = file_put_contents("tmp.zip", fopen("https://github.com/MyGithub/MyRepo/archive/master.zip", 'r'), LOCK_EX);

if(FALSE === $f)

  echo 'Couldn\'t write to file<br>';
  $zip = new ZipArchive;

  //open tmp.zip
  $res = $zip->open('tmp.zip');

if ($res === TRUE) {

  //extract to tmp folder
  $zip->extractTo($sync_address);
  $zip->close();
  echo 'Successfully opened or extracted zip file.<br>';

} else {

  echo 'Falied opening or extracting zip file.<br>';

}

   //foreach extracted folder only in tmp (as we only want folder & files inside the first github archive folder IE MyRepo-master.zip/MyRepo/actual structure
   $directories = glob($sync_address . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);

   foreach($directories as $dir) {
   $directoriesSync = glob($dir . '/*');
   echo '<br>'.$dir.' Folder Exists <br>';

   //move files & folders to root folder
   //does not work, no files moved
   //works if move folder set as root folder/another folder/
   rename($dir, $sync_move);

   //for each directory & file move via cmd
   //move files & folders to root folder
   //does not work, no files moved
   //works if move folder set as root folder/another folder/
   foreach($directoriesSync as $dirSync) {
     shell_exec('mv '.$dirSync.' '.$sync_move.'');
     echo 'Successfully moved '.$dirSync.' to '.$sync_move.'<br>';  
   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed

```
shell_exec('mv '.$dirSync.' '.$sync_move.'');
```

to

```
shell_exec("cp -r $dirSync $sync_move");
```

and worked successfully